# SVG / vector graphical objects boolean operations (union, intersection, subtraction)

Tags: java, c, ruby, svg, computational-geometry

I have 2D closed vector paths, specified in [SVG paths-like syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp) - i.e. these paths include straight lines and various Bezier curves. Is there anything like a small, nice & discrete library (preferably in C, Java or Ruby, but any language will do if this library is clean and easy to use) that allows to do boolean operations like union, intersection and subtraction with these paths?

What I've found so far includes:

- Huge and pricey commercial vector graphic products (such as Autodesk AutoCAD or Adobe Illustrator) that can be called using some sort of API or scripted to do boolean 2D paths operations - which is clearly an overkill for my purposes.
- Inkscape developed in-house [lib2geom](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Lib2geom) library which lacks documentation, bindings, has some compilation issues, seems to be used in no projects besides Inkscape itself and looks fairly complex.
- [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/) is a huge and pretty complex computational geometry library, that works in pretty weird object space (i.e. you have crazy mix of templates, imperative style functions to do operations on these templated data structures, etc, etc), and doesn't seem to have sane bindings to other languages beside C++. Python bindings to CGAL seem to be abandoned and don't look very friendly to me.
- [JTS](http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm) seems to be GIS-centred and deals only with straight lines, while I need to deal with SVG-like Bezier curves.

So, the question is, is there are any other small, nice & easy libraries floating around to deal with boolean operations on SVG-like paths?

Comment: Are you looking for some geometric data structure out or for just a visual representation of the results?

Comment: I'm looking for: 1) data structure, 2) boolean operations with polygons and curves; I don't need visualization libraries, i.e. Cairo or something similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but wouldn't the classes in the `java.awt.geom` package suit your needs? They deal with two-dimensional shapes; the [`Area`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class deals specifically  with boolean operations:

> An `Area` object stores and manipulates a resolution-independent description of an enclosed  area of 2-dimensional space. `Area` objects can be transformed and can perform various 
>   Constructive Area Geometry (CAG) operations when combined with other `Area` objects. The CAG operations include area addition, subtraction, intersection, and exclusive or.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be almost exactly what I need on the first glance - it's strange how I overlooked it.

Comment: Is it possible to use this library to create graphic objects (union of 100 circles, some of them overlapping, a few isolated, for example), and then export to svg or pdf? If yes, could you give some directions? Thanks!

Comment: @qed, the `java.awt.geom` package deals with 2D shapes exclusively. Exporting to SVG or PDF requires additional libraries such as Batik and iText, respectively. As far as I know, both libraries have some sort of `Graphics2D` implementation that you can draw on.

Comment: You mean it's possible to draw those shapes in java.awt.geom then export the result to pdf through Batik?

Comment: @qed, Batik is the SVG library and iText generates PDF files, but that's the idea, yes.

Answer (score 3):

You can [JavaScript Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsclipper/) ,a port of [Angus Johnson's Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) (written in Delphi, C++, C# and Python), which in turn is based on [Bala R. Vatti's clipping algorithm](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=129906). It is able to handle all polygon cases, including the self-intersecting ones.

Keep in mind that the lib takes only *polygons* so [any curves need to be polygonized](https://gist.github.com/Phrogz/845901) first